# ConvertTo-JSON from string - access JSON fields by name in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

How can I access a field like $body.uuid?
This is what I have tried:

```
$body = @"
{   "uuid": "Test07",
    "subject": "Template07-Subject",
}
"@

$bodyJSON = ConvertTo-Json $body

Write-Host $bodyJSON
Write-Host "uuid=$($bodyJSON.uuid)" 
Write-Host "uuid=$($bodyJSON.$uuid)"
```

Results:

```
"{   \"uuid\": \"Test07\",\r\n    \"subject\": \"Template07-Subject\",\r\n}"
uuid=
uuid=
```

Comment: The string already contains json - you want `$object = ConvertFrom-Json $body; $object.uuid`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tried ConverFrom-JSON and it gave: ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your `$body` variable contains a JSON string.

  - Unless your intent is to *embed* that string in *another* JSON string, do not call [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) on it - the latter's purpose is to convert *objects* to *JSON strings*.
- In order to parse the JSON string into an *object* (graph), pass it to [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json), which returns `[pscustomobject]` instance(s).

  - You can use regular property access, such as `.uuid` on the resulting object(s).

Note:

- As [bluuf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4910940/bluuf) points out, your original JSON contains an extraneous `,` after the `"subject"` property, which makes it technically malformed - this has been corrected below.
- Note, however, that `ConvertTo-Json` in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) still accepts such JSON, whereas *Windows PowerShell* does not.

```
# Create a string containing JSON
$body = @"
{   
    "uuid": "Test07",
    "subject": "Template07-Subject"
}
"@

# Parse the JSON string into a PowerShell object (graph).
$bodyAsObject = ConvertFrom-Json $body

# Now you can use property access.
$bodyAsObject.uuid  # -> 'Test07'
```

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation.  The comma was there because I delete a bunch of other fields to create a smaller test case, and forgot about it.  I didn't catch that was the reason for the error with ConvertFrom-Json.   So bottom line, PowerShell doesn't have a JSON object concept then.  Instead it uses pscustomobject to simulate that?

Comment: @NealWalters, yes, it's easy to forget a trailing comma, which is why some JSON parsers conveniently ignore it. To PowerShell, JSON is just a _string_ - a text-based _serialization format_ that must be deserialized into a language-specific object graph (including in JavaScript with `JSON.parse()`). In PowerShell, you use `ConvertFrom-Json`, which returns an [array of] [nested] `[pscustomobject]` instance(s).